# c++ code analysis - fatal error C1093: API call 'GetUserString' failed '0x8013110e' :

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-analysis

Any ideas what this error message means?  It seems like some obscure compiler error that only occurs when we run with code analysis on.  Our solution compiles without code analysis turned on.

Comment: Please provide us with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is very difficult to answer a question about code compilation issue when we can't see any code that is failing.

Comment: I have the same Problem when I run code analysis from the commandline like this `msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true`. When I remove `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true` it compiles fine.